# adding a progress indicator inside a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following button:

http://jsfiddle.net/TU6vQ/

and I wanted to add a loading spinner next to the 'Invite your friends' text. How do I do so?
The spinner is [here](http://www.gifstache.com/images/ajax_loader.gif).

Is this spinner going to be a div inside a button? Or what is the easiest way to do so? I also wanted to show the spinner on a button click.

This is the simple button I have:

```
 <button id="inviteYourFriends" class="arvo-bold button blue" >
            Invite your friends
        </button>
```

Answer (score 7):

If you make the button relatively positioned, you can absolutely position the spinner inside of the button:

http://jsfiddle.net/TU6vQ/8/

HTML:

```
<button id="inviteYourFriends" class="arvo-bold button blue" style='position:relative'>
     <img src="http://www.gifstache.com/images/ajax_loader.gif" class='spinner'/>
            Invite your friends
</button>
```

CSS:

```
.spinner { 
    position: absolute; 
    right: 5px; 
    top: 6px; 
    width: 25px; 
    height: 25px;
    display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
$('button#inviteYourFriends').click(function() {$('.spinner').show();});
```

Answer (score 1):

Put spinner inside of button, give it absolute positioning, and relative on the button.  The button is a block level element, you don't need an additional div around it all.

Answer (score 0):

I updated the jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/TU6vQ/5/):

```
<div style='position:relative'>
    <img src='http://www.gifstache.com/images/ajax_loader.gif' style='position:absolute; width:16px; margin:10px 10px; height:16px;' />
<button id="inviteYourFriends" class="arvo-bold button blue" >
            Invite your friends
        </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Also allows you to position it at your will, hide and show it.

Comment: So does putting the image inside of the button

Comment: I didnt know that, just position it like the div?

Comment: If the button is relative positioned, you can put the image inside of it and position it whereever you want, including outside of the button by using negative positions or margins.  You can also hide and show it.  The button in of itself is a container, just like the div.

Answer (score 0):

The `button` tag can support `img` tags like almost any other element, and so all you need to do is put the image inside it; as simple as it sounds.

```
 <button id="inviteYourFriends" class="arvo-bold button blue" >
            <img src="http://www.gifstache.com/images/ajax_loader.gif" height=10> Invite your friends
        </button>
```

On your button click just prepend your button contents with the image. Voila.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this.

http://jsfiddle.net/YQNn4/

HTML

```
<img class="progress" src="http://www.gifstache.com/images/ajax_loader.gif" height="20px" width="20px" alt=""> 
<button id="inviteYourFriends" class="arvo-bold button blue" >
            Invite your friends
</button>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.progress').hide();
    $('#inviteYourFriends').click(function(){
        $('.progress').show();
    });
});
```

Comment: He wants the spinner INSIDE of the button, not above it

Answer (score 0):

i would add the image inside the button element, then position and size it using css.
here is the jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TU6vQ/9/

here's the code:

```
<button id="inviteYourFriends" class="arvo-bold button blue" >
            Invite your friends
        <img src="http://www.gifstache.com/images/ajax_loader.gif" alt="..." class="spinner"/>
        </button>
```

CSS:

```
.button {
    line-height: 52px;
    font-size: 16px;
    width: 270px;
    height: 50px;

     text-shadow: -1px -1px 1px rgba(175,175,175,.42);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 38px;
    color: #fefefe;
    font-size: 14px;
    display: block;
    height: 38px;
    border: 0;

    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
       -moz-border-radius: 4px;
            border-radius: 4px;

    -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
       -moz-background-clip: padding;
            background-clip: padding-box;

    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
       -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.1); 
       -moz-box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
            box-shadow: 1px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}

.button.blue {
    background: rgb(169,191,200);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(169,191,200,1) 0%, rgba(169,191,200,1) 51%, rgba(143,170,182,1) 54%, rgba(143,170,182,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(169,191,200,1)), color-stop(51%,rgba(169,191,200,1)), color-stop(54%,rgba(143,170,182,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(143,170,182,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(169,191,200,1) 0%,rgba(169,191,200,1) 51%,rgba(143,170,182,1) 54%,rgba(143,170,182,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(169,191,200,1) 0%,rgba(169,191,200,1) 51%,rgba(143,170,182,1) 54%,rgba(143,170,182,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(169,191,200,1) 0%,rgba(169,191,200,1) 51%,rgba(143,170,182,1) 54%,rgba(143,170,182,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(169,191,200,1) 0%,rgba(169,191,200,1) 51%,rgba(143,170,182,1) 54%,rgba(143,170,182,1) 100%);
}

.spinner
{  
    margin-top:8px;
    margin-left:5px;
    height:20px;
    width:20px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

Comment: No offence, but how is this any different than the other answers here?

Comment: the difference was about 8 mins in posting time. after posting and reading the others i see they are all very similar, but they all differ slightly. though i think yours is the best because you included the jquery to show it on click, i also think ur comment to me was unnecessary.